# Is it possible to print Powerpoint slides after all automation on a slide is done?

Tags: ms-office

I have slides that turn certain parts into another color after 1 click, generated with MS Office Powerpoint for Mac.

Similarly I have slides where pictures shrink to show text underneath after 1 click.

I wonder if it is possible to print those slides after the animation completes?